# On git push I got error: error: invalid protocol: wanted 'old new ref'

Tags: git, gerrit, git-push

I have branch x. I type `git push origin x:y`

I got error message

```
error: error: invalid protocol: wanted 'old new ref'
fatal: internal server error
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Counting objects: 140, done.
```

Maybe it is imporant: when I cloned repository, for performance I used switches

```
-b master --single-branch
```

git version 2.6.2.windows.1

gerrit version 2.9.4

Comment: try " git push origin HEAD:refs/for/x "

Comment: @love "Pushing to refs/for/* creates code reviews which must be approved and then submitted". I don't want review because `y` is my private branches to keep source safe.

Comment: Have you tried "git push -u origin x:y" ?

Comment: @love yes, result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Git/Gerrit is your Gerrit server running?

https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T86304

> it's related to shallow clones; git 1.7 can push from shallow clones
>   in some cases (including a fresh clone, which is what g-p-u does), and
>   git 1.9 can always push from shallow clones if the server supports it.

If your Gerrit server does not support pushes from shallow clones you may not be able to use

> --single-branch

Answer (score 5):

When I decided to final investigation of the issue, it revealed that

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

solves the problem.

(Solves means allows push a branch, not push branch with shallow clone)